# The phrase "were strong from"

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, phrase-requests

I want to make a sentence like the following:

> His arms were strong from lifting
>   weights.

I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct though. When I googled "were strong from" only 3 pages came up. Why is that?

If it's not grammatically correct, then what could I use instead?

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly grammatical, nothing is wrong with it, but probably you might want to use present tense:

> His hands **are** strong from lifting weights.

Either way, both are correct.

Comment: I agree. "His arms were strong from lifting weights" sounds like a description of a character in a book. "His arms are strong from lifting weights" sounds like how I would describe someone to my friend.

Comment: We have no idea how he's using the sentence. Both tenses work in certain situations
.

Comment: @jackgill: you should be ashamed of yourself. I clearly said both are correct. You only down-voted my answer, because you are competing with your answer.

Comment: I have the feeling that using the word **from** to mean **as a result of** is perhaps somewhat informal/slangy, and I don't see that switching to present tense somehow make it more acceptable. But in the end I don't have a problem with OP's example anyway, so I'm happy to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds perfectly grammatical to me. I probably would change it to:

> He had strong arms from lifting weights

to avoid it sounding like the arms themselves were exercising.

Comment: or "His hands are strong from his lifting weights." thereof

Comment: yes, but this sounds awkward to me